# How to pause a Threading.timer to complete a function

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synchronizing a timer to prevent overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684200/synchronizing-a-timer-to-prevent-overlap)

I have a `Threading.Timer` in my class.

```
 System.Threading.Timer timer;
 TimerCallback cb = new TimerCallback(ProcessTimerEvent);
 timer = new Timer(cb, reset, 1000, Convert.ToInt64(this.Interval.TotalSeconds));
```

and defined a callback for it.

```
private void ProcessTimerEvent(object obj)
{
  if(value)
    MyFunction();
}
```

When run it, re-running callback before `myfunction` to complete.

How to pause `Threading.Timer` to complete `myfunction`?

Comment: I think you want to prevent [timer overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684200/synchronizing-a-timer-to-prevent-overlap).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is not necessary to stop timer, you could let the timer continue firing the callback method but wrap your non-reentrant code in a Monitor.TryEnter/Exit. No need to stop/restart the timer in that case; overlapping calls will not acquire the lock and return immediately.

```
object lockObject = new object();

private void ProcessTimerEvent(object state) 
 {
   if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
   {
     try
     {
       // Work here
     }
     finally
     {
       Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I created a `NonOverlappingTimer` class using this pattern that wraps System.Threading.Timer to guarantee non-overlapping executions: https://gist.github.com/randyburden/fe0febe315d7887b2471c7328a95fe5e#file-nonoverlappingtimer-cs

Answer (score 17):

You can disable a `System.Threading.Timer` by changing the interval.  You can do this by calling:

```
timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
```

You'll have to change the interval back once you have finished calling `myfunction` if you want the timer to continue firing again.