# .NET 6 PeriodicTimer with top-of-the-minute timing

Tags: c#, .net, timer, .net-6.0, periodictimer

.NET 6 introduced the [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-6.0).

I need to do something every minute, at the top of the minute. For example: `09:23:00`, `09:24:00`, `09:25:00`, ...

But with a one minute period - `new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))` - and starting at `09:23:45`, I will get "ticks" at: `09:24:45`, `09:25:45`, `09:26:45`, ...

So it's dependent on the start time.

My workaround is a one-second period, and a check that the current time has seconds equal to `0`. Another workaround is to wait for the next minute and then start the timer. Both approaches work but are fiddly and use too fine a resolution.

Is there a built-in or better way to trigger at the *top of the minute* rather than one-minute-after-start?

Comment: All the previous timers like System.Threading.Timer allowed you to specify both an offset and a period so the job could start at a specific time. Why use `PeriodicTimer` if you don't really need asynchronous waiting? Even then though, you can emulate the initial offset with `async Task.Delay(target-DateTime.Now);`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, but I like this new one because of its async capabilities. I wish it had more functionality though. Your comment has a nice workaround, thank you.

Comment: That said, if you want to schedule jobs it's better to use a purpose-built library like Hangfire or Coravel. There's a lot more to running jobs than just making a callback every 1 minute

Comment: What async capabilities are you looking for? Previous timers executed their callback in a threadpool thread. That callback could be async itself.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was using it as in example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71637260), for a hosted service.

Comment: The question is wrong. Server timers are asynchronous. Only `System.Windows.Timer` is synchronous because it uses Windows messages and runs on the UI thread. [System.Threadin.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-6.0) `executing a method on a thread pool thread at specified intervals.` The timer itself doesn't run anywhere, it's an OS service. You can have an `async void` callback if you want.

Comment: Besides, even after `await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync()` where will *your* code run? You'd be back in the BackgroundService sync context, running on a single threadpool thread. Just like Threading.Timer. The *real* difference is that if your job takes too long, a `System.Threading.Timer` will fire again and execute concurrently with the old job, while the `await` loop won't.

Comment: Your workaroud (one-second period and checking for seconds=0) might spradically fail. Because timers are not 100% exact it might happen that you get an event at 01:01:59.999 and the next at 01:02:01.001 (so none with seconds=0) or an event at 01:01:00.001 and the next at 01:02:00.999 (so two with seconds=0).

Comment: @KlausGütter that's why timer libraries run at higher frequencies. It's not just 1ms either, the OS timer resolution is 16.5 ms. For jobs scheduled by the minute or even by seconds though, milliseconds don't matter. If you want really accurate timers you'd have to use the specialized multimedia timers that ... aren't exposed in .NET

Comment: @KlausGütter the question of skew appears almost every week when someone tries to naively animate UI elements using a normal Timer and encounters freezing or skips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there is nothing like this available in the standard .NET libraries. And I don't think that it's likely to be added any time soon. My suggestion is to use the third party [Cronos](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos) library, that does a good job at calculating time intervals¹. You can find a usage example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883959/how-to-start-my-worker-service-on-the-hour/71885865#71885865), by Stephen Cleary. What this library does is to take a `DateTime` and a Cron expression as input, and calculate the next `DateTime` that satisfies this expression. It is just a `DateTime` calculator, not a scheduler.

If you want to get fancy you could include the functionality of the Cronos library in a custom [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer)-like component, like the one below:

```
using Cronos;

public sealed class CronosPeriodicTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CronExpression _cronExpression; // Also used as the locker
    private PeriodicTimer _activeTimer;
    private bool _disposed;

    public CronosPeriodicTimer(string expression, CronFormat format)
    {
        _cronExpression = CronExpression.Parse(expression, format);
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> WaitForNextTickAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        PeriodicTimer timer;
        lock (_cronExpression)
        {
            if (_disposed) return false;
            if (_activeTimer is not null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("One consumer at a time.");
            DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
            TimeSpan minDelay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
            DateTime? utcNext = _cronExpression.GetNextOccurrence(utcNow + minDelay);
            if (utcNext is null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unreachable date.");
            TimeSpan delay = utcNext.Value - utcNow;
            Debug.Assert(delay > _minDelay);
            timer = _activeTimer = new(delay);
        }
        try
        {
            // Dispose the timer after the first tick.
            using (timer)
                return await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(cancellationToken)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally { Volatile.Write(ref _activeTimer, null); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        PeriodicTimer activeTimer;
        lock (_cronExpression)
        {
            if (_disposed) return;
            _disposed = true;
            activeTimer = _activeTimer;
        }
        activeTimer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Apart from the constructor, the `CronosPeriodicTimer` class has identical API and behavior with the [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer) class. You could use it like this:

```
private CronosPeriodicTimer _timer = new("0 * * * * *", CronFormat.IncludeSeconds);

async Task DoSomethingPeriodicAsync()
{
    while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync()) // Dispose the _timer to stop
    {
        // DoSomething
    }
}
```

The expression `0 * * * * *` means *"on the 0 (zero) second of every minute, of every hour, of every day of the month, of every month, and of every day of the week."*

You can find detailed documentation about the format of the Cron expressions [here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos#cron-format).

**Caution:** The `CronosPeriodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync` method calculates the interval until the next tick at the time it is invoked. In case the system clock is adjusted while a `WaitForNextTickAsync` operation is in-flight, the tick will not happen at the correct time according to the adjusted system time.

The 500 milliseconds `minDelay` has the intention to prevent the remote possibility of the timer ticking twice by mistake. Also because the `PeriodicTimer` class has a [minimum period](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/71905) of 1 millisecond.

The `TimeSpan period` parameter in the `PeriodicTimer`'s constructor has an upper limit of approximately 49 days and 17 hours. In case the `_cronExpression.GetNextOccurrence` call produces a `DateTime` further in the future than this, the `CronosPeriodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync` call will fail with an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception.

For an implementation that uses the [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) method instead of the `PeriodicTimer` class, and so it can be used by .NET versions previous than 6.0, you can look at the [3rd revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72739676/3) of this answer.

¹ <sub>With the caveat that the [Cronos library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cronos) is currently [capped to the year 2099](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos/issues/51#issuecomment-1173334262) (version 0.7.1).</sub>

Comment: All the server timers do this already, by allowing an initial delay. A simple `await Task.Delay(startTime-DateTime.Now)` before creating the timer will do the trick. Cronos uses the same timers and probably works at a higher frequency to avoid skews. The *real* difference between `PeriodicTimer` and `System.Threading.Timer` is that `System.Threading.Timer` will fire whether the callback is still running or not, while `PeriodicTimer` allows only a single execution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `probably works at a higher frequency` I didn't know the .net framework exposed such detail. Interesting.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the Cronos library knows nothing about frequencies. All it does is to take a `DateTime`, and calculate the next `DateTime` based on a Cron expression. What you'll do with the resulting `DateTime` is up to you.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias what's the point of all this code then? You end up doing what the OP's code did, only worse, because now you depend on the single-fire timer inside `Task.Delay`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the point is to delegate the calculation of the `GetNextOccurrence` to a well-tested third party library ([Cronos](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos)). And also to allow a potential future reconfiguring of the schedule in a declarative way ([Cron expression](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos#cron-format)) instead of complicated imperative coding. The overhead of using a single-fire timer instead of periodic-fire timer is likely to be minuscule. The .NET timer-related infrastructure is highly optimized, and can handle scheduling thousands of timers per second with ease.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here are the workarounds mentioned in my question.

Tick every second, and wait for top-of-the-minute:

```cs
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(cancellationToken)) {
  if (DateTime.UtcNow.Second == 0)
    await DoSomething();
}
```

Delay till top-of-the-minute, then tick every minute:

```cs
var delay = (60 - DateTime.UtcNow.Second) * 1000; // take milliseconds into account to improve start-time accuracy
await Task.Delay(delay);
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(cancellationToken)) {
  await DoSomething();
}
```

Some notes about accuracy:

- This will never be perfectly accurate, as discussed in the comments above. But it's good enough in many cases.
- Small clock drifts will occur and make the per-minute timer more and more inaccurate, and this will only be fixed when the server is restarted. But the per-second timer "self-corrects" on every tick, so although it's "heavier", it will be more accurate over time.
- The per-second timer can sometimes lose a tick or get a double tick (see comments above). The per-minute timer won't lose ticks, but they may be inaccurate. Whether this matters is something for you to consider.

Comment: You could use `await Task.Delay(target-DateTime.Now); var timer =....` to start the timer on a specific time. Or use one of the other timer classes. The [Backround Tassks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) doc page shows how to create a timed background service using System.Threading.Timer. Instead of `Timespan.Zero` for the initial delay you can use `target-DateTime.Now`

Comment: On the other hand, all timers slip, and even the libraries run at *higher* frequencies, checking the target time, just like *your* code does. The OS can delay until it schedules the callback. Or, there may be many jobs. The library won't use a new timer for every one, it will use a single timer and check for jobs to execute when it fires

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your solutions btw. Complexity has its own cost which may be just too much if you don't care about millisecond accuracy. If you did, you'd need a multimedia timer too, normal timers and libraries wouldn't work. The *real* difference is that `PeriodicTimer` allows only one execution at a time. Sometimes that's important, sometimes it's not. A `PeriodicTimer` can be used to ensure HTTP calls are made in specific intervals for example, as an easy way to throttle

Comment: If anything, this is a better solution than the accepted one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. I'm conflicted though as he put in effort to help me, was first to answer, and I did learn about the Cronos lib which seems very popular. :)

Comment: Both solutions are practical, and get the job done. None of them is perfect though. The first is somewhat inaccurate and inefficient, while the second does not auto-adapt to system-wise clock adjustments. You could probably improve slightly the second solution by including the `DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond` in the calculation of the `delay`.

Comment: The second solution is efficient and reasonable, sacrificing a bit of precision (however much latency exists in the first callback will affect all later waits).  The first solution isn't even correct, you absolutely need to do edge detection (look for a change in the minute field) and not level detection (because any jitter at all can result in zero or two matches instead of one).

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks. Do you have an example that shows what you mean?

Comment: Klaus gave one correct and one incorrect example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72739162/net-6-periodictimer-with-top-of-the-minute-timing/72739940?noredirect=1#comment128482410_72739162  His second example should have been "01:02:00.001 and the next at 01:02:00.999"