# Scheduling application to run different methods at different times on new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, scheduler

I have a WinForms application which needs to run around 100 different methods at different times of the day / time of day on a given day. The methods need to run in their own threads to avoid one method having to wait for another.

I need a concise way to be able to add tasks. I've tried the following but I'm not certain that this is the correct approach and the code is not actually working. There's an error on the line:

```
ScheduledTask customTask = CreateScheduledTask(SomeTask, timeToRun, 1);
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Create a `ScheduledTask`.
2. Add the `ScheduledTask` to a list of `ScheduledTask`s.
3. Send the list to `ScheduleTask`s which will run the method at the appropriate time.

   ```
   internal class testingClass
   {

    public class ScheduledTask
    {
        public string? TaskName { get; set; }
        public TimeOnly ExecutionTime { get; set; }
        public Action? Action { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<ScheduledTask?> CreateScheduledTask(Func<Task> action,
        TimeOnly executionTime, int? desiredDay = 0)
    {
        return new ScheduledTask
        {
            TaskName = "CustomTask",
            ExecutionTime = executionTime,
            Action = async () =>
            {
                if (desiredDay == 0)
                {
                    // Run every day
                    await action();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Run once a month on the specified day
                    if (DateTime.Now.Day == desiredDay)
                    {
                        await action();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public async Task SomeTask()
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public void InitializeScheduledTasksAsync()
    {
        TimeOnly timeToRun = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        ScheduledTask customTask = CreateScheduledTask(SomeTask, timeToRun, 1);
        List<ScheduledTask> scheduledTasks = new List<ScheduledTask>
        { customTask };

        ScheduleTasks(scheduledTasks, 900);
    }

    public void ScheduleTasks(List<ScheduledTask> scheduledTasks,
        int intervalMilliseconds)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(intervalMilliseconds);

        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {

            TimeOnly currentTime = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);

            foreach (var task in scheduledTasks.ToList()) 
            {
                if (currentTime == task.ExecutionTime)
                {
                    if (task.Action != null)
                    {
                        // Execute the task's action
                        task.Action.Invoke();
                    }

                    // Remove the task from the list (if it should not repeat)
                    //scheduledTasks.Remove(task);
                }
            }
        };

        timer.Start();
    }

   }
   ```

Comment: A `System.Timers.Timer` already runs callbacks in a background thread. If you want to run the Action in another thread, use `Task.Run(task.Action)` instead of `task.Action.Invoke`. You should rename the variables and the `Action` property too, because `Task.Run(task.Action)` just begs for bugs. `Job` is a far better name. You can run all jobs at the same time with `await Task.WhenAll(scheduledTasks.Select(t=>Task.Run(t.Action)));` but that will lead to thrashing if there are more CPU-bound jobs than there are cores. Another option is to use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` to limit concurrent execution

Comment: Maybe use the [windows task scheduler](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler)? That might be more appropriate for infrequent jobs. Otherwise you have `Threading.Timer`, use one per job, calculate the time remaining until the job should execute, and call `.Change()` with an infinite period. Reset the timer once the job has completed.

Comment: It feels a little odd to be running this many scheduled tasks in a WinForms app, especially with it running for such a long time. This is not a resilient solution. You would likely be better off with a Windows Service or ASP.Net app, and running something like Hangfire to do the scheduling.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm not 100% clear on what you mean. Do you mean that I should keep adding to a list of ScheduledTask and then update ScheduleTasks? Is the logic that I've used correct?

Comment: @JonasH, thanks, I'll check it out. I have 3 types of jobs. 1. Every x minutes. 2. At a certain time every day. 3. At a certain time on every certain day of the month.

Comment: Few solutions to this, windows scheduler, Coravel, Quartz, Hangfire to name a few.  Really depends on what you need.

Comment: @DavidG, I'll take a look at Hangfire. I've put it on a WinForms app to give user feedback for now. I'll probably move it over to a Windows Service at some point.

Comment: I suspect Hangfire would do all the feedback you need

Comment: Related: [.NET 6 PeriodicTimer with top-of-the-minute timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72739162/net-6-periodictimer-with-top-of-the-minute-timing).